# Is there a way to disable PageView clipping effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let say I have a PageView sized {100x100} with 4 children, so there will be only 1 child visible at the time, until I scroll to the second child. What I want is to make all 4 children are visible on the screen. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear. What are you trying to achieve. Some visual reference would help.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've updated the question with some visual as your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, What did you use to create a visual?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Just Photoshop -> export to GIF

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question is kind of funny, but I'm doing it anyway, thought that someone might need this.

Thanks to this post: [Non-center alignment for PageView with viewportFraction < 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948087/non-center-alignment-for-pageview-with-viewportfraction-1-0/53953783#53953783)

Now I can apply `PageScrollPhysics()` to a `ListView` to achieve this effect.
Like this:

```dart
var _listView = ListView(physics: PageScrollPhysics());
```

As @Ferdi said, `PageView` is not designed for this. So just go with `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView()` and apply the `PageScrollPhysics()`, it will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You're question seems a bit unclear indeed. I assume what you want is to see all our `PageView` in a single screen.

Well in not why `PageView` was created for.

Here a brief description of `PageView`:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A

And here's the official doc for [PageView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)

Also if you still want the effect I would suggest you to encapsulate your four `PageView` (actually change to `Container`) into a row with a global `gestureDetector`.

Hope it's help !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated the question with visual.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can achieve this with the `PageView`. Define a `PageController` with a view port fraction you need.

Example:

```
final PageController _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.3333); 
//(0.3333 i.e 1/3 indicates to fit 3 tiles on view port, for 4 use `0.25` i.e `1/4`)
```

then pass the controller to the `PageView`

```
PageView(
  controller: _controller,
  children: [...] // your page widgets
)
```

Hope this helps!