# Non-center alignment for PageView with viewportFraction < 1.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When you create a PageView with a viewportFraction value of <1.0 for the PageController, the pages are snapped to the center of the viewport, like so:

[image]

I want the current pages to be snapped to the top of the viewport, while the next page is rendered under the bottom bar. I've tried applying a transform to each page:

```
Transform.translate(offset: Offset(0.0, -36.0), child: page)
```

This appears to work at first glance (see first image), but fails to render the next page when it would be hidden without the transform (see second image):

[image]
[image]

I've thought of using a ListView with PageScrollPhysics (which does behave correctly), but then I lose the pagination APIs (the ability to see which page I'm on/jump to a page). What would be the appropriate way to do this, in a way that always renders the next page when it's on-screen?

Comment: Just a suggestion, completely unverified or tested, but could you go with ListView and use the scroll offset divided by the page height to determine the current page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881103/current-scroll-offset-inside-a-flutter-listview-sliverlist-etc

Comment: Hmm, that could work. Let me try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually trying to achieve something similar, I did ask a question here: [Is there a way to disable PageView clipping effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943805/is-there-a-way-to-disable-pageview-clipping-effect/53946125#53946125)

But thanks to you, your thought of approaching with ListView & PageScrollPhysics is just brilliant, I can solve it now. For calculating the page, you just need to do this:

```
ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
controller.addListener((){
  int page = (controller.offset / viewportWidth).round();
});
// which "viewportWidth" is the width of your page item.
```

or if you want to animate to a specific page, do this:

```
int page = 3;
controller.animateTo(
  page.toDouble() * viewportWidth,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  curve: Curves.ease,
);
```

Comment: Turns out the physics are slightly off when the actual viewportWidth is less than the widget width (at the end, it tries to snap to something beyond bounds), but this math  makes it possible to write the physics. 

I just made a copy of PageScrollPhysics and changed all the position.viewportWidth references to an itemExtent passed in the constructor, while clamping the pixels to position.maxScrollExtent.

Comment: @yunyu could you show the code to your fix? I have the same issue where the page snapping is of.

Answer (score 1):

PageView has padEnds property, if you set it to false and viewPortWidth < 1, then you will see your cards pushed to the left side.

See the code below and result:

```
child: PageView(
        padEnds: false,
        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.95),
        children: widget.cards
            .map((e) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0), child: e))
            .toList(),
      ),
```

[image]